# Change system app permissions through ADB

Tags: applications, system

I'm new in the Android world and have my first problem. I tried to change the default launcher on my Android TV stick (MK808B, Android 4.4).

I have set the permissions with ES File Explorer to read and write on the old launcher to back it up, and then copy the new one to replace the old one. After that, I pushed the Home button to start the new launcher, but all I get is a black screen with the upper control elements.

I think I have to set the permissions to the new launcher, but I'm having a black screen now. ADB works, but I don't know how to set the permissions to my launcher.apk or to read out the name of the app to change `chmod`.

How do I get this Launcher running?

Answer (score 1):

To revoke the camera permission

```
$ adb shell pm revoke <package name>  android.permission.CAMERA
```

To grant the camera permission

```
$ adb shell pm grant <package name>  android.permission.CAMERA
```

Comment: Is there any reason why it is the camera permission specifically? Or is this just an example to grant/revoke permission using ADB?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed it. I only use

```
adb shell am start -n com.estrongs.android.pop/.view.FileExplorerActivity
```

to start my explorer app.

Now I was able to do it with my default UI.